# generic repository doesn't let me add methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, repository, iqueryable

I'm building an ASP.NET Core web application. The controller use a generic repository within methods like "Get, GetById, Post, Update ecc.". When i use these methods in the controller and I try to add methods like "Include, Where ecc." pops this error : CS1501 :

"No overload for method 'method' takes 'number' arguments"

```
var license = await _repo.GetSingleById(id).Include("product");
```

i tried to return also IQueryable but it gaves me the same error.

Comment: If `GetSingleById` returns a single item, you're already past the point where you are able to use `Include` since the query has already been executed. Also, `Include` has parameters, otherwise what are you trying to actually include?

Comment: so in this case i shouldn't use a repository right?

Comment: Repository is fine, but you either need to pass in the `Include` expressions as a parameter or return an `IQueryable`

Comment: @DavidG Can you show me that as code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetSingleById` is almost certainly returning a single item, and that means you're already past the point where you are able to use `Include` since the query has already been executed. So your simplest option is to pass in the `Include` expressions whenever you need them. First let's assume you have an existing function that looks like this:

```
public async T GetSingleById(int id)
{
    return _context.Set<T>()
        .Single(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

You would need to change it to something like this instead:

```
public async T GetSingleById(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();

    if(includes != null && includes.Any())
    {
        foreach(var include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
        }
    }

    return query.Single(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
// As before without any includes
var license = await _repo.GetSingleById(id);

// A single include
var license = await _repo.GetSingleById(
    id, 
    e => e.Product);

// Multiple includes
var license = await _repo.GetSingleById(
    id, 
    e => e.Product, 
    e => e.SomethingElse);
```

Note that I have specifically used the lambda syntax for includes rather than the string overload. These are much safer to use since they give you compile-time checking.

Comment: this code gives me the following error : "CS0266". VS gives me this tip of to add an explicit casting => (DbSet<TEntity>)query.Include(include); but this is the error : "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'IncludableQueryable`2[Joshua.Model.Licenza,System.Object]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Joshua.Model.Licenza]'."

Comment: Oops sorry, that is my fault for writing untested code. Try again.

Comment: how can i make the parameters optional? passing null and with the nullable operator right? This is the IRepository ==> Task<TEntity> GetSingleById(TypeKey id, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[]? includes); And the error is the following : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I already showed how to do that above. It's a `params` parameter so you just leave it blank.

Comment: so with "params" it's automatically optional right?

Comment: @DavidG I dont know how you managed to find what type it is within the line 'return query.Single(e => e.Id == id);' as the type is generic?

Comment: @Computer OPs code is generic, it probably has a constraint on the generic type that ensures a property called `Id` exists.