# How to introduce TProperty for method in generic class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In a standard class if i wanted to include ProductImages table for all the products as part f my query, i could write something like

```
from prods in dataContext.Products.Include(i => i.ProductImages) select prods;
```

I now want to turn this into a generic method so no matter what source it is, it would be able to include the table i require. I started off with a generic method (leaving out the class declaration for brevity T is declared as part of the class i.e. `Public Class<T>`):

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _entities;
    }
```

This works with no matter what source i have whether it be a product table or customer table i can  pass in the table and it returns that object (so T can be a Product or Customer). I now want to introduce the `Include` functionality.

I start off by looking at the source code for `Include` which is

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path)
        {
            Check.NotNull(source, "source");
            Check.NotNull(path, "path");
            if (!DbHelpers.TryParsePath(path.Body, out var path2) || path2 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(Strings.DbExtensions_InvalidIncludePathExpression, "path");
            }

            return source.Include(path2);
        }
```

however i noticed it has an additional `TProperty` which i dont know where or how i should implement this into my generic method?

I attempted to do the following based on the source

```
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T>> path);
```

but again i dont know how to configure/introduce the TProperty (or equivalent) in this fashion so it works like my first example?

Comment: Why abstract the query away at all?  As it is GetAll will be loading the whole table in memory everytime which is fine for testing and breaks horribly after deploying

Comment: I dont follow what you are suggesting or what issue there maybe? Usually each Entity would have GetAll and then that class uses that method where applicable to GetAll the data and then filter it down as required for another method.

Comment: I made an answer recently that might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72812558/1663001

Comment: @Computer since GetAll returns an enumerable `Customer.GetAll().OrderByDescending(c => c.LastPurchased).First()` will load all customers into memory and *then* picks the one with the latest purchase.

Comment: Interesting topic about this kind of interfaces https://ayende.com/blog/3958/the-dal-should-go-all-the-way-to-ui

Comment: `DbContext.Set<T>()` is all you need (or any `DbSet<T>` property in the context). There's absolutely no gain in wrapping `DbSet` in generic higher-level methods (as usually happens in the overrated repository pattern).

Comment: `DbContext.Set<T>()` is a generic repositoryfactory which returns generic repositories. That means OP is trying to wrap a generic repository with a generic repository.